# ng-repeat handling array of object and subArray

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angularJS with a node back-end that sends data using socketio. I'm then trying show the data using ng-repeat.

My Response Data :-

```
[
 {
   day: 1,
   messages:[
     {msg: 'We have reached a certain level of authenticity'},
     {msg: 'You had a chat with Falon'},
     {msg: 'I have 2 stories to complete'}

   ]
 },
 {
   day: 2,
   messages:[
     {msg: 'We have to add more resources.'},
     {msg: 'You had a chat with Falon and Isha'},
     {msg: 'Story 2 is still incomplete'}

   ]
 },
 {
   day: 3,
   messages:[
     {msg: 'Thanks for having a Chat with Isha.'},
     {msg: 'Conflict Resolution done between Remo and Amit'},
     {msg: 'Story 2 completed. Moving to Story 3'}

   ]
 }
]
```

My Controller Code : -

```
app.controller('report', function($scope, $timeout, $http) {
  console.log('Reports Page');

$http.get("/reports")
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.ourGrouper = 'today';
    var messages = response.data;
    $scope.contents = messages;
    console.log($scope.contents);
  });
});
```

My HTML Code : -

```
<div id="accordion" class="accordion-style" ng-controller="report">
  <div class="card" ng-repeat="(key, value) in contents | orderBy: 'day' | unique: 'day'">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading{{$index}}">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse{{$index}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse{{$index}}">
          Day {{value.today}}
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse{{$index}}"  class="collapse" ng-class="!$last ? 'class-for-last' : 'show'"  aria-labelledby="heading{{$index}}" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body" ng-repeat="(key, value) in contents | groupBy: 'id'">
        {{value}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My Current Output :-

[image: Current OutPut Screen Shot]

As you can see here all the object result are present in each day, 'angular.filter' is not helping much.

My Expected Output in the accordian :-

```
**Day 1**
   We have reached a certain level of authenticity
   You had a chat with Falon
   I have 2 Stories complete

**Day 2**
   We have to add more resources
   You had a chat with Falon and Isha
   Story 2 is still incomplete

**Day 3**
   Thanks for having Chat with Isha.
   Conflict Resolution done between Remo and Amit
   Story 2 completed. Moving to Story 3
```

Answer (score 0):

As you provided you response data, when you **first loop using ngRepeat**, your **key start from zero**, and **value will be your first result object**.

```
 {
   day: 1,
   messages:[
     {msg: 'We have reached a certain level of authenticity'},
     {msg: 'You had a chat with Falon'},
     {msg: 'I have 2 stories to complete'}

   ]
 }
```

Now to access value of day [Ex. day:1], you need to write `{{value.day}}`. And to print messages you need to loop again using `value.messages` so you can print every message from `value.messages`.

```
<div id="accordion" class="accordion-style" ng-controller="report">
      <div class="card" ng-repeat="(key, value) in contents | orderBy: 'value.day' | unique: 'value.day'">
        <div class="card-header" id="heading{{$index}}">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse{{$index}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse{{$index}}">
              Day {{value.day}}
            </button>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse{{$index}}"  class="collapse" ng-class="!$last ? 'class-for-last' : 'show'"  aria-labelledby="heading{{$index}}" data-parent="#accordion">
          <div class="card-body" ng-repeat="(msg_key, msg_value) in value.messages">
            {{msg_value.msg}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: @jack this works but, I'm getting a ngRepeat:dupes error

Comment: It is due to same key used in two ngRepeat loops. Check it out code, there must be same key twise

Comment: We don't need key in either of ngRepeat loop. Just remove key and msg_key from loop and try.